# JQGrid empty grid and no navigation or edit icons

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

For some reason, my grid is blank with no rows (not even an empty row), no navigation icons and no editing icons. I'm using a few add-in features such as an autocomplete field (inside the grid), and a font resizing script so my script is a bit long. The page is receiving the properly formatted response from my functions page and it seems to match my jsonReader settings but it's not populating the grid with it. Here is my JSON formatted response from the page:

```
{"page":"1",
"total":1,
"records":"4",
"rows":[{"DetailID":"1","Quantity":"2","TaskName":"Differencial With Housing","UnitPrice":"335.00","ExtendedPrice":"670.00"}, {"DetailID":"2","Quantity":"1","TaskName":"Left axel seal","UnitPrice":"15.00","ExtendedPrice":"15.00"},{"DetailID":"3","Quantity":"1","TaskName":"Upper and Lower Bearings","UnitPrice":"55.00","ExtendedPrice":"55.00"}, {"DetailID":"5","Quantity":"1","TaskName":"Fluids","UnitPrice":"45.00","ExtendedPrice":"45.00"}]}
```

And here is my grid script:

```
<script>    
    function autocomplete_element(value, options) {
      var $ac = $('<input type="text"/>');
      $ac.val(value);
      $ac.autocomplete({source: "autocomplete.php?method=fnAutocomplete"});
      return $ac;
    } 
    function autocomplete_value(elem, op, value) {
      if (op == "set") {
        $(elem).val(value);
      }
      return $(elem).val();
    }
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#filter').jqm();
                var selectedRow = 0;                
                $("#list").jqGrid(
                {
                    url:'managegrid.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    colNames:['DetailID', 'ProjectID','Qty.','Description','Unit Price','Total Cost'],
                    colModel :[
                        {name:'DetailID', index:'DetailID', hidden:true, editable:false},
                        {name:'ProjectID', index:'ProjectID', width:25, hidden:true, editable:true},
                        {name:'Quantity', index:'Quantity', editable:true, width:50, align:'right', edittype:'text', editoptions: {defaultValue:'1'}},
                        {name:'TaskName', index:'TaskName', editable:true, width:450, align:'left', edittype: 'custom', editoptions: {'custom_element' : autocomplete_element, 'custom_value' : autocomplete_value}},                           
                        {name:'UnitPrice', index:'UnitPrice', editable:true, width:100, align:'right'},
                        {name:'ExtendedPrice', index:'ExtendedPrice', editable:false, width:100, align:'right'}
                    ],
                    onSelectRow: function(id){
                      if(DetailID && DetailID!==mkinline){
                        jQuery('#list').saveRow(mkinline);
                        jQuery('#list').editRow(DetailID,true);
                        mkinline=DetailID;
                      }
                    },
                    pager: $('#pager'),
                    rowNum:20,
                    rowList:[],
                    pgbuttons: false,
                    pgtext: null,
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    sortname: "DetailID",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    imgpath: '/js/jquery/css/start/images',
                    caption: 'Project Details',
                    height:'auto',
                    width:823,
                    mtype:'GET',
                    recordtext:'',
                    pgtext:'',
                    editurl:"editgrid.php",
                    toolbar:[true,"bottom"],
                    loadComplete:function(){
                            var recorddata = $("#list").getUserData();
                            $("#t_list").html(recorddata.MSG);
                        },
                    jsonReader: {
                        page: "PAGE",
                        total: "TOTAL",
                        records:"RECORDS",
                        root: "ROWS",
                        userdata:"USERDATA"
                        }
                    }
                );
                $("#t_list").css("color","blue");
                jQuery("#list").jqGrid("inlineNav",'#pager',{edit:true,editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",add:true,addicon: "ui-icon-plus",search:false}, {}, {},
                {url:"delgridrow.php",closeAfterDelete:true,reloadAftersubmit:false,afterSubmit:commonSubmit,caption:"Delete",msg:"Delete selected",width:"400"})
                .navButtonAdd('#pager',{caption:"",title:"Reload Form",buttonimg:'/js/jquery/css/start/images/refresh.gif',onClickButton:function(id)
                    {
                        resetForm();            
                        $("#list").setGridParam(
                            {
                                url:"managegrid.php",
                                page:1
                            }
                        ).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    }
                });         
            }       
        );
    function gridSearch()
    {
        var pid = $("#DetailID").val();
        var qty = $("#Quantity").val();
        var tn = $("#TaskName").val();
        var up = $("#UnitPrice").val();
        $("#list").setGridParam(
            {
                url:"managegrid.php?ProjectID="+pid+"&Quantity="+qty+"&TaskName="+tn+"&UnitPrice="+up,
                page:1
            }
            ).trigger("reloadGrid");
        $("#filter").jqmHide();
        return false
    }
    function commonSubmit(data,params)
    {
        var a = eval( "(" + data.responseText + ")" );
        $("#t_list").html(a.USERDATA.MSG);
        resetForm();
        return true;
    }   function resetForm()
    {
      window.location.reload(false);
    }
</script>
```

I've been trying to figure this one out all weekend and it's driving me crazy so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). If you use *not free jqGrid*, then you have to call `navGrid` *before* `inlineNav`.

Comment: Not sure of the version number but the builds came directly from the jquery download page about 2 years ago.I'm actually in the process of converting a ColdFusion based invoicing app over to PHP. This grid worked in the CF version so all the links to the jquery and jqgrid folders have been preserved. And the grid is rendering, it's just not being populated with the data. (and the navigation/edit icons aren't showing either)

Comment: Do you added the line of code `jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", '#pager', {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});` directly before calling of `inlineNav` like I wrote before?

Comment: I already have this line in my code:

Comment: Yes, this is the code now:

    jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", '#pager', {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});
                    jQuery("#list").jqGrid("inlineNav",'#pager',{edit:true,editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",add:true,addicon: "ui-icon-plus",search:false}, {}, {},...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the line of code

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", '#pager',
    {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});
```

directly before calling of `inlineNav`.

**UPDATED**: Your code have many other problems too. For example, you should remove `jsonReader` option from your code, because it contains wrong values of properties (like `root: "ROWS"` instead of `root: "rows"`, which is default and can be removed). You can consider to use `jsonReader: { id: 'DetailID' }` to use the value of `DetailID` as the rowid and to use `DetailID` instead of `id` during editing. I'd recommend you to define all variables before the usage (see `mkinline` and `DetailID` for example).

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I downloaded the newest version of the Guriddo build and now I'm getting the edit icons and a message that there were no records. (although the managegrid.php page is still responding with the json data)

Comment: @RaymondMeade: You are welcome! You should at least remove `jsonReader` additionally or to replace it to `jsonReader: { id: 'DetailID' }`: see **UPDATED** part of my answer. The hidden column `DetailID` can be removed after that. By the way Guriddo is not free (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). On the other side [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, can be used completely free of charge.

Comment: Well what do you know, I removed the jsonreader and my grid is now working. Thank you so much, Oleg (now on to fixing the autocomplete feature that isn't even getting any response data...lol)

Comment: @RaymondMeade: You are welcome! I wrote before that your current code has many problems. By the way, you don't need to use `edittype: 'custom'` to use `autocomplete`. It's enough to call `autocomplete` inside of `dataInit`.

Comment: Oleg, if I switch over to your jqgrid build, will I have to make any changes to my code?

Comment: @RaymondMeade: Free jqGrid contains many enhancements, which you can use, but I tried to make it maximally compatible with old jqGrid 4.x. Thus your existing code should work without any required changes. Just modify the URLs from which you loads jqGrid files and load it from CDN directly (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) and test your code. Next step: you can use  Font Awesome Icons [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data)